# C++ Reading ints and strings from file

Tags: c++, string

I have a file that looks like :

```
4
Sam Stone
2000
Freida Flass
100500
Tammy Flass
5000
Rich Raptor
55000
```

I am trying to read from it, but the first getline in the while loop always returns nothing. The int 4 gets read correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 60;


struct person
{
    string name;
    double money;
};

int main()
{
    char filename[SIZE];
    string input;
    char inputs [50];
    int value;
    int count = 0;
    vector<person> Members;

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("carinfo.txt");
    if (!inFile.is_open()){ cout << "Could not open fle"; }

    inFile >> value;
    Members.resize(value);

    while (inFile.good())
    {
        inFile.getline(inputs, SIZE); //getline(inFile, input, '\n');
        inFile >> value;

        count++;
    }
    cout << "Total lines = " << count;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SIZE` is 60 but `inputs` only has size 50 (should probably be `SIZE`) ?

Comment: why are you using `inFile.getline(inputs, SIZE);` instead of `getline(inFile, input);`? The last one is definitively more elegant since it doesn't need `SIZE` at all. Just don't fiddle with `char`s in C++. There is no need for that.

Comment: tried both they did not work. getline(inFile, input, '#')  gonna try this

Comment: Ok. So i needed 2 getlines and the first getline was reading the carriage-return it seems.  But how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a blank line in the file?

Comment: You really should improve your question. Why do you implement a struct and a vector that holds items of that struct, if you never even assign one value? Questions with code should contain a compilable code which is the minimal code that exhibits that behaviour.

Comment: Yes. problem was the first getline was reading the carriage-return. Should I store each line as string then convert to int for the number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using `std::string` and `op>>(std::istream, person)` to read the elements, this works for me

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

struct person
{
    std::string name;
    double money;
};

//read in 1 person
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, person& p) {
    is >> p.money;
    is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::getline(is, p.name);
    return is;
}

int main() {
    //open stream
    std::ifstream file("fname");
    //create vector, let the stream operators do the hard work
    std::vector<person> v((std::istream_iterator<person>(file)),
                           std::istream_iterator<person>());

    std::cout << "count: " << v.size();
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator

Comment: It's the `ignore` bit important in this answer, not all the rest.

Comment: @Van S go ahead! if there is something you don't understand about it just ask

Comment: @111111: Yes, my question is any suggested read? I never knew C++ could be so.. elegant.

Comment: @111111:  What is the purpose of istream& operator>>..  does it overload the istream or something?

Comment: @Vans Yes C++ can be elegant it's just outshadowed by the reams of bad code out there. If by that you mean book then yes, Accelerated C++ is a great started,  once you have got through that then "Effective C++" is a great book on style and good practice as is "Effective STL" and "Exceptional C++".

Comment: @VansS the purpose of the operator `>>` overload is to provide a basic deserialisation function for user defined types, in the same way `std::string` and prmitives can be taken from streams